# Reasons as to why standard multiple regression would not be appropriate?

Tags: regression, linear

A researcher is investigating the effects of various doses of poison on two common varieties of cockroaches. She administers six different ranges of the poison dose to 20 cockroaches of each species, and records how many cockroaches die. The data (numbers of cockroaches killed out of 20) appear in the following table:

[image]
The researcher proposes to calculate the proportion of cockroaches killed for each dose of poison and species, and to model this proportion in terms of dose (a quantitative variable) and species (a qualitative variable) using a standard multiple regression. The response variable will be proportion, while dose and species will be the predictor variables.

[image]

Comment: Show the raw data, not grouping dose into intervals.  Standard multiple linear regression assumes that conditional on $X$, $Y$ has a normal distribution with constant variance.  Neither of those conditions are true for your problem.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks for that. I knew about the distribution but not variance. What would be a more suitable method of analysis and why?

Comment: you dont need regression for this problem. Take simple percentage of killed to all cockroaches. Spcies 1 0 15 25 50 75 100
Species 2 25 40 75 90 100 100

Comment: Binary logistic regression, which makes no distributional assumptions.  Run it on the raw binary responses.

Comment: You have small counts -- skewed, discrete, heteroskedastic. ... I agree this is a case where logistic regression seems an obvious first thing to think of

Comment: Thanks. The data of proportion killed vs log10(dose) looks like it would fit into a straight line.. (see photo above in the question). What would be a suitable modelling technique to describe the proportion of cockroaches killed for species 1 in terms of poison dosage administered?

Comment: Very much so - a regular logistic in log dose would be a good choice if dose could never be zero.

Comment: But first redo the plot on the logit proportion scale.

Comment: @Glen_b I usually imagine logistic regression as a regression model for the probability of success of a Bernoulli RV, as a function of some predictors (in this case `species` and `dose`. Instead than successes or failures, here what we measure are counts...I'm not saying that using log reg is wrong here, but could you explain me how this connects with the idea of modeling a Bernoulli-distributed response?

Comment: @FrankHarrell Great. What will I need to do to redo the plot? I simply plotted dose vs proportion died..

Comment: Logistic model assumes the logit proportion is linear in dose (or in log dose if you transform).  logit = log(p/(1-p)) = log odds of response where p=proportion.  Easy to relax this assumption using regression splines or quadratic, etc.

Comment: @Delta At each dosage you have 20 cockroaches, some of whom die. If you're not used to conceiving of a binomial GLM as actually modelling a binomial response, consider that each individual cockroach's response will be a 0 (didn't die) or 1 (died) and model the whole thing as Bernoulli.

Comment: @Luvpsi It can't really be linear, though; consider what such a model would predict for the proportion dead for a dosage of 1/10th as large as the smallest dosage there (i.e. with x near -1)  ... it would predict a proportion of about -1/20 !! ... similarly at larger doses than those observed it would suggest a proportion above 1. So that relationship has to bend at the large and small doses -- indeed if the response is to be smooth (and presumably it will be) then it must curve inside the range of the observed values, because the ends are already essentially at the extremes.

Comment: @Glen_b good point - in this case Bernoulli or Binomial are the same (apart from a constant which doesn't matter for MLE estimation of regression coefficients) because the number of cockroaches $n_i$ is the same for every $i=1,\dots,N$.  But what if $n_i$ changed with $i$? I know logistic regression is used there too. Will estimatea still be the same for the Bernoulli and for the Binomial model? I guess so, but if you have a link that let would be appreciated.

Comment: Try writing the likelihood either way.

Comment: @Glen_b I will try, but how do I write the probability mass function of $\mathcal{B}(n_i, p)$? Do I just use the usual expression in terms of the Binomial coefficient? Or should I consider that $n_i$ is a random variable, and thus I should assume some probability distribution (uniform?!) for it? My difficulty is that since $n_i$ is different among different observations (*in the general case!* Not here where we always have 20 cockroaches), I'm not sure if I should consider an hierarchical model, or if that would just be a waste of time.

Comment: The $n_i$ differ but are fixed - you choose how many cockroaches to test at each level of treatment; the likelihood (under independence) is the product of each of the binomial likelihoods.

Comment: Excellent! It is now making a lot of sense.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you take $\log_{10}$ of the dose because it was initially skewed to the right? I think a more interesting question would be to have an ordinal outcome variable representing that the dose had no effect all the way up to the dose caused death. You could then use an ordinal probit regression model and estimate the $\text{ED}_{50}$ and $\text{LD}_{50}$ of the poison.

Comment: @guest1234 It is not likely this is the common log of the dose, unless we are doing homeopathy: no measurable dose will cover 20 orders of magnitude!  I believe the OP mistakenly labeled the x-axis in the plot, that's all.  Although your references to ED and LD are apt, it is fairly evident that this is a textbook problem with synthetic data.

Answer (score 5):

The really interesting aspect of this question is that **the doses are recorded as intervals and those intervals span sizable portions of the total range.** This means we should be concerned that standard procedures, like logistic regression, that represent the doses as *individual numbers* might be misleading.

By means of visualizations, I will take you step-by-step through a simple (and no means thorough) analysis until we arrive at the final complex but highly illuminating graphic.  Your time might best be used by skimming down the plots, then backing up to study anything that captures your interest.

---

[image: Figure 1: raw data shown as intervals.]

Let's look at this more closely.  Suppose that any given dose $x$ (not a range--an actual dose) is associated with a chance of $p(x, s)$ that any cockroach of species $s$ will die in these experimental conditions.  Further suppose that cockroach deaths are (statistically) independent.  (This assumption can in principle be tested; for now, it is needed because relevant information for testing it is unavailable.)  This is a *Binomial Generalized Linear Model* (albeit without a specified link function--yet).

These assumptions can (and should) be written mathematically so that we can determine an appropriate procedure to estimate $p(x,s)$.  Consider a cockroach of species $s$ that was administered a dose $x$ between $a$ and $b$ units.  The indicator of its death is a random variable taking the value $1$ with probability $p(x,s)$.  The total number of deaths of $20$ such individuals is the sum of $20$ such variables, where $x$ ranges between $a$ and $b$ as determined in the experiment.  If $x$ were fixed, that total would therefore have a Binomial$(20, p(x,s))$ distribution.  But if $p(x,s)$ varies over that interval $(a,b]$, then the total has a different distribution.

To make further progress, we have to specify how $p$ might vary with $x$.   A standard, simple way is with a "logistic link function" where the log odds of death are assumed to be a linear function of dose.  Equivalently, let's suppose

$$p(x,s) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + \exp{\left(\alpha(s) + \beta(s)x\right)}}$$

for numbers $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ that could differ between the two species.  (This gives two competing models: when $\alpha$ or $\beta$ differ between the species the model has an "interaction.")

In the next plot, $x$ values were randomly assigned (independently) within each interval (limiting the "20+" interval to the range 20-25) and the model without interaction was fit.  The curves plot $p(x,s)$ for $s=1,2$.

[image: Figure 2: One fit superimposed on the plot of the interval data]

The uncertainty arising from recording each dose only with its interval can be assessed by repeating this random selection of possible doses within the intervals.  For the next figure, 100 models were fit.  The doses within each interval were chosen according to various scaled Beta distributions with randomly-selected parameters; some of those parameter choices could cause most of the doses to be near one end of an interval or another.  For each iteration the same Beta distribution, appropriately scaled, was used in each interval: thus, doses might be consistently chosen near the low ends or near the high ends of the intervals.

[image: Figure 3: 100 fits superimposed on the interval data]

To combine the two assessments of uncertainty--prediction error as estimated within the model and variation due to uncertain location of the doses within each interval--the last figure superimposes all 100 "error polygons" (as shown in the second figure above).

[image: Figure 4: 100 error polygons transparently superimposed on the data]

Most of the data fit nicely within these visual envelopes.  The only exception is the observation of no deaths for Species 1 (red) at a dose of 0-1 units: its interval, plotted in the bottom left corner, appears to be a little low.

---

I will end by saying a little more about the "interaction."  For all 100 datasets, *both* models were fit (with and without interaction). Just as an analyst might do in practice, the no-interaction model was chosen unless the model with interaction was determined to be "more significant" than the one without interaction.  The decision was made by comparing the AICs of the models, referring the difference to a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution, and setting the significance level at $95\%$.  What actually happened is that in *every* case, the no-interaction model was chosen.

Visually, no interaction means that the fitted curves are horizontal translates of each other: that is, there will be some constant $\mu$ for which $p(x,1)=p(x-\mu,2)$ for all $x$.  You can see this in the second figure above: the fit (black curve) for Species 1 is about $\mu=9$ dose units to the right of the fit for Species 2.  One might interpret this as follows:

> The susceptibility of Species 2 to the dose is about the same as giving nine more units of the dose to an individual of Species 1.

As an example of what effect this dynamic model selection might have, let's alter the data a tiny bit.  Suppose that $12$ instead of $20$ deaths were observed in Species 1 at a dose of "20+".

[image: Figure 5: Data with fits and error polygons, altered data]

Now, fairly frequently, the data appear to have different "shapes" for the two species.  The models with interaction fit steeper dose-response curves to Species 2 than to Species 1.  **What is especially interesting** is how these overlapping fits and error envelopes collectively account for (a) uncertainty computed within each model, (b) uncertainty due to how doses were recorded, and now (c) uncertainty due to the analyst's choice of model.

Comment: I think this is great! (+1). What I don't fully understand: How did you choose the parameters for the Beta distribution? I would have thought that 100 replications are too small to cover a relevant portion of possible Beta distributions? Also, I wasn't aware that the difference of AICs are $\chi^{2}$ distributed. I'm only familiar with the informal "rules" (e.g. a difference of 2 in AIC denote essentially similar fits).

Comment: @COOL I was hoping to gloss over those issues :-). The theory says twice the difference of log likelihoods will be $\chi^2(2)$ distributed (I forgot, when carrying this out, that the models differ by *two* interaction terms). That's probably a more standard way that people would carry out model selection in this context. I chose the parameters for the Beta distributions in such a way as to assure that in some cases most of the $x$ values would be selected from close to the left endpoints, in others near the right endpoints, and in yet others would be scattered throughout each interval.

Comment: (Continued) The point of the Beta distributions was not to model the doses probabilistically: they were merely a convenient tool to generate a broad range of possible values of the doses consistent with the interval data.  What matters most is to make the distributions of doses strongly dependent between intervals, because this has the greatest effect on the fits and is a realistic possibility.  *E.g.,* maybe the experimenters consistently used the smallest dose in each interval, even though they reported them only as being within the intervals.

Comment: This can easily be extended to a PhD on cockroach health. It would be great to continue this research to study long term effects of exposure to poisons on cockroach quality of life and conditional life expectancy after the incidents, maybe develop antidotes and other options to help the survivors of poison attacks. Cockroach community would appreciate the attention

Comment: Ive been around long enough now to tell this was a whuber answer before scrolling to he bottom. A small masterpiece.